# How to package JS app in Azure Build Pipeline and Save in Separate C# Respository

Tags: javascript, c#, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

TL;DR - Using two separate repositories (because that's how I've inherited them) I'm attempting to run a custom script to build a JS-only app that is then copied and deployed along with a C# API app that's housed in a second respository.  Using Azure DevOps Services (cloud-based) for repos and pipelines.

As I've indicated above I'm working my way through the process of running these scripts to create a single .js file that's ready to be deployed with our API (the JS app is called and created by a variety of our applications using this API).  My conundrum is how to approach this using Azure's Build Pipe as I can run the scripts but where the file(s) created are then being stored (and where to reference them) and then taking that file and inserting this creation into the repository of the C# API app, thereby kicking off a second build that would then deploy the C# app to the appropriate service.

In another JS project I've successfully copied the files in my build pipes to then push these 'builds' to the appropriate environments but I'm at a loss for copying a specific file, following the `npm run build-prod` step to save and then insert a file in a known static location to the second repository.  NOTE: both repositories are located in the same organization.

Here's my uber rough draft YAML for the JS application:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build-prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build-prod'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(agent.builddirectory)/dist/'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/closet-api.js'
    ArtifactName: 'closet-api.js'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Your help is appreciated!

12/2/2019 Minor Update
I've updated my YAML to appropriately run my custom build script (contained within the JS file) and grab the required file.  Now the conundrum is a more thorough understanding on where exactly this file is located so, in another project in a separate build pipe, I may grab the .js file and use it in my C# project.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: npm run build-prod
  displayName: 'Run Build Script for Prod'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy client-api.js file to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: '**\dist\closet-api.js'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: closet-api.js
```

**Next update**
Looks like grabbing the created .js file is easier than I anticipated in the C# project pipeline.  Now I'm working out how to insert the file into the C# repo prior to the build for the C# project.

```
#Code from C# project grabbing published .js file

- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: #'(insert the .js project number here)'
    definition: '7'
    specificBuildWithTriggering: true
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```

Comment: Sorry not totally get your point. What do you mean `Save in Separate C# Respository` Did you just want to commit all of that generated build artifacts with JS app  into that C# Repo?  You have mentioned that two repos are in the same organization. Did them also in same team project?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the repos are not in the same project, only in the same organization.  From what I've been able to piece together it appears that there should be a way for me to temporarily 'store' the artifact from the JS build pipe.  My thought then is inside the build pipe for the C# project is to grab the particular file needed from already-built JS artifact; the C# build pipe can then proceed along as normal and build the project like any other .NET app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trial and effort I've been able to finagle a workaround that appears to complete this stage of the project:

**TL;DR**

1. Download build artifact from the path I'd specified in the JS build pipe (in this case `downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'`)
2. Copy file to specified file path within C# project and overwrite existing file

```
steps:
#Download JS app from published JS Build Pipe
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '(project identifier here)'
    pipeline: '7'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    downloadType: 'specific'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\folder-name-where-item-was-saved'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\directory\where\I\want\built\file'
    OverWrite: true
```

Now I've got to begin the effort to trigger a pipeline from another pipeline, but that's another day and another dollar.  Continuing on the redesign of our deployment process.

Comment: As a quick side note I've found rather than having two separate projects it makes much more sense to create separate repos within the same project.  This is how I ended up solving my 'one pipeline kicking off another' conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a third pipeline where you can download the artifacts from your C# API and your JS app, then you can organize them and deploy to target server. Here is an example for you:[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Part of what I'm attempting to detangle is *where* exactly these artifacts are being stored once built (or how to temporarily 'store' them) so I can then pick up that file from the artifact and insert into the repository where the C# project sits.

Comment: The trouble is, as currently constructed, the JS file needs to be incorporated _into_ the C# project prior to compiling due to legacy architecture decisions.

Comment: Ok Austin, I am getting your requirement. You need to create a pipeline with three jobs- first will build the js project , second will download the artifact of js project and then build the C# project and in the job you can copy artifacts from JS and C# project then build it. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Gaurav.  Yes more details would be helpful, namely, **the location of the published files** (see above YAML I updated 12/2/2019) so I may grab them with the build pipe of the C# project.  Are these files stored centrally within the organization and available across projects?

Comment: look at my latest YAML; grabbing the .js file from within the C# build pipe was easier than I anticipated.  Now I'm attempting to commit that file into the C# repo to replace the current .js file (same name) and proceed along with the build for the C# project.  Recommendations?